# Galleriffic: it loads before my Jquery code that refers objects inside it

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a problem with [Galleriffic](http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/), a popular jQuery plung-in to show images with HTML near them.

In this HTML, I have an image, used as a button: `<img class="my_button" src="img/button.gif" />`

Between the `<head>` and `</head>` tags, I have this jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".my_button").click(function(){
    $.get("page.php",function(data)
    {
      $('#mydiv').html(data);
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

The problem is that the jQuery code loads **before** Galleriffic, so there is no button when the `$(".my_button").click(){}` event is loaded.

Is there a way to force Galleriffic to load before the jquery code?

Here is some code to be more clear as possible:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".my_button").click(function(){

$.get("pagea.php",function(data)
{

$('#mydiv').html(data);
});
});
});
</script>

///some html

<script type="text/javascript" src="Galleria Borse/js/jquery.history.js"></script>
// Galleriffic libraries calls
<!-- We only want the thunbnails to display when javascript is disabled -->
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('<style>.noscript { display: none; }</style>');
</script>

<div class="navigation-container">
<div id="thumbs" class="navigation">
<a class="pageLink prev" style="visibility: hidden;" href="#" title="Previous Page"></a>
<ul class="thumbs noscript">
//and other galleriffic containers and divs
<img class="my_button" src="img/button.gif" /> //this is the button

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { //some Galleriffic code (Jquery code) }
```

I tried to put the code `$(".my_button").click(function(){});` everywhere: inside the body, at the bottom of the page and even into the Galleriffic libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
  //some Galleriffic code (Jquery code) 
  // Initialize Minimal Galleriffic Gallery
  $('#thumbs').galleriffic({
    imageContainerSel:      '#slideshow',
    controlsContainerSel:   '#controls'
  });
  $(".my_button").click(function(){
    $.get("pagea.php",function(data){
      $('#mydiv').html(data);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried, but the jquery code still loads before the buttons appear, this time loads after the "prev_photo" and "next_photo" links, but the rest of Galleriffic is loaded after my code.

Howefer i have  // Initialize Advanced Galleriffic Gallery _  instead of:  // Initialize Minimal Galleriffic Gallery _ and more code than your example... if it can be useful...

Comment: I have found a solution, it's not so elegant but it works.
First of all i put my jquery code in the $(window).load(function() 
instead of (document).ready(function($) so it will be run after the  whole page loads.

But when i changed the photo in the content of Galleriffic the button stopped to work because the event was bound only to the first button loaded.
To solve this i also put my Jquery code in the Galleriffic function called 
"function pageload(hash)" just before the "return" statement so it is refreshed any time i change the content of Galleriffic.

Comment: spent an entire morning and half afternoon after this, i only hope that this will be useful to someone ;)

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but anyway :). There is a solution to do this and you can even place your code into

> `$(document).ready();`

the problem is, as you said, that when you want to bind click event, there is nothing to bind it to. So, why not to bind it to something different. There is a posibility with

> .on()

since jQuery 1.7 (or so). In this version .on took functionality of .bind, .delegate and .live as well.
We are interested in .delegate kind of style :).

So instead of

```
$(".my_button").click(function(){})
```

use

```
$('#foo').on('click','.my_button', function(){})
```

what that does is, that you are binding `.on event` to `#foo`, which can be just anything, that is on the page from the beginning (lets say `$(document)`). And saying "trigger click event when you see some `.my_button` clicked. That means, that when the `.my_button` finally arrives, it will work :).

And by the way this is a way to solve another problem with Galleriffic "harcore" customization :). It is the only way to attach action to the main slideshow image(or its wrapper), since galleriffic is still removing and appending those structures.